# Do I need to normalize data before applying L1, L2 norm in ANN

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, overfitting

I wish to train the ANN and use regularizers to avoid overfitting. I need some suggestions, is it mandatory to normalize the data before using L1, L2 regularizers. I would highly appreciate if you can cite book/article with suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you don't use regularization, it is highly advised that you normalize your data before inputting to a neural network as it'll significantly affect the gradients. So, yes, you should normalize it.